# General question regarding convergence of double integrals.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, divergent-integrals

While studying double integrals, a student is certainly presented with the following property:

**Property.** *Given two functions $f$ and $g$ that are integrable over the rectangular region $R$ (region stands for $R$ being open, connected, nonempty subset of $\mathbb R^2$), if $f(x,y) \leqslant g(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$ in $R$, then*
$$ \iint_R f(x,y) dx \, dy \leqslant \iint_R g(x,y) dx \, dy. $$

With some further thoughts on this property, a student can try to relate this (somehow) with convergence of double integrals. I have searched in the web about the expression 'double integral convergence', but not much results arise.

For example, let's say we're dealing with a non-pretty looking function $g.$ Then, one might say that it would be easier to find a function $f$ that satisfies the conditions of the property above to conclude something about the double integral of $g$, over $R$.

One interesting situation would be - What happens when we find a function $f$ such that
$$ \iint_R f(x,y) dx \, dy = \pm \infty \quad ?$$
In other words, what happens in the case where the integral above is divergent ? **Can we conclude that the integral of $g$ over $R$ is also divergent? Does this result directly from the property stated?**

Comment: I think so. It also means that it diverges faster than $f$

Comment: There is a **"Corner"** Case , which you did not consider : [[1]] When Double Integral $f$ is $-\infty$ , Double Integral $g$ **"might"** be Convergent. [[2]] When Double Integral $f$ is $+\infty$ , Double Integral $g$ **"must"** be Divergent.

Comment: @Prem That makes total sense. But do you know where can I find a more formal proof of this fact? For example, assume that $$  \iint_R f(x,y) dx \, dy = +\infty.$$ Then, from our inequalities it follows that $$ \iint_R g(x,y) dx \, dy \geqslant +\infty.$$ Saying something is bigger than infinity is a bit non sense, no?

Comment: @Rodrigo $\int\int_R g=\infty$, in that case. "$=\infty$" is just shorthand for, the integral diverges (the limit process that defines the integral is always diverges to $+\infty$)

Comment: @FShrike I am familiar with that. But I was just wondering: if something is bigger or equal than infinity, then, this 'something' is infinity? In other words, does the following inequality always hold (and how would you justify it) ? $$ \iint_R g(x,y) dx \, dy \geqslant +\infty \implies \iint_R g(x,y) dx \, dy = +\infty.$$

Comment: $\ge\infty$ has no meaning other than $=\infty$ in this context. It requires no justification either because the symbols are being used loosely anyway or because you have accepted that integration is defined in the extended reals, in which case $x\ge\infty\iff x=\infty$ is true by definition

Comment: Consider $x < x+1$ : Even when $x$ tends to $+\infty$ , it is true. Consider $x^2 < x^3$ : We end up with $+\infty < +\infty$. Nothing Wrong. It is ok to claim $f < g$ when both tend to $+\infty$. [ We have No Contradiction in "Some Infinity is larger than Some Other Infinity" ]